# Fstab stopped working

Tags: mount, fstab, ubuntu-mate

I have a second drive, sdb with 3 partitions.

Here is what my desktop looks like. SDB1,SDB2,and SDB5 are not there?

Which means I can not access anything on that drive.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the mountpoints be full paths instead of relative ? /SDB1_Mountpoint instead of SDB1_Mountpoint, and similar for the two others. And what do the/dev/loop and /dev/sd lines do in the bottom (every thing after the line with /swap ..) ? It looks like output from `blkid`or similar.

Comment: @SorenA they're probably providing the output there from blkid for us to see what is actually present on-system that fstab references.

Comment: @ Soren A  I added the backslashes, but the drives still do not mount.

Comment: I tried mount: /SDB1_Mountpoint: /dev/sdb1 already mounted on /SDB1_Mountpoint. But I still can not see the drive.

Comment: I got this to work. thunar /SDB1_Mountpoint/Ubuntu_Mate_18.04 Caja is set to show mounted volumes but for some reason it is not working.

Comment: So fstab **didn't** stop working? your question is really about the caja file manager?

Comment: I really do not know what stopped working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain in detail what your actual problem is.

Comment: @Organic Marble I did some edits.